# Setting the name of an arraylist object java - homework

Tags: java

I have a homework problem that I have been working on for quit a while now. I am creating objects which are shapes then putting them in an arrayList then putting a collection of those shapes in another array list. Then drawing the shape as a picture all at one time. I need to name them so I can use the name of the collection Picture to draw the text file. I got the program working (it draws the shapes correctly) but when set the name of the picture then get it, it returns null. I believe that it is because my method I am not properly passing the name. Of Course help would be Greatly appreciated.

```
//read in text from file
start picture A   // I want to name the picture A
circle 100 100 20
rectangle 100 100 20 30
draw A  // I want to draw picture A


import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.*;

public class Driver {

private static String fileName;
private static String line;
private static Graphics g;
private static char[] name1;




public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<Picture> collection = new ArrayList<Picture>();

    try {
        readLines(collection);
    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

static void readLines(ArrayList<Picture> collection) throws Exception {
    Picture<Shape> pictures = new Picture<Shape>();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Please enter the file name ---> ");
    fileName = input.next();

    FileReader fr = new FileReader(fileName);
    BufferedReader inFile = new BufferedReader(fr);

    // loop through lines
    while ((line = inFile.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
        txtAnalysis(line, collection,pictures);

    }

    // close file
    inFile.close();

}

public static void txtAnalysis(String name, ArrayList<Picture> collection, Picture<Shape> pictures ) {



    if (line.startsWith("start picture")) {
        String picName = line.split(" ")[2];
        pictures = new Picture<Shape>();

        //set the name here
        pictures.setName(picName);


        //here it works
        System.out.print(pictures.getName());
    }

    else if (line.startsWith("circle")) {
        String[] parts = line.split(" ");
        int x = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
        int y = Integer.parseInt(parts[2]);
        int z = Integer.parseInt(parts[3]);


        //new object circle
        Circle c1 = new Circle("circ", x, y, z); 

        //add object
        System.out.println("calling add " + c1);
        pictures.addShape(c1);


    }
    else if (line.startsWith("rectangle")) {

        String[] parts = line.split(" ");
        int x = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
        int y = Integer.parseInt(parts[2]);
        int z = Integer.parseInt(parts[3]);

        //new object rectangle
        Rectangle r1 = new Rectangle("rect", x, y, z); // small and upper

        //add object

        pictures.addShape(r1);  
    }

    else if (line.startsWith("draw")) {
        collection.add(pictures);

        //problem here
        pictures.draw(pictures.getName());


        //returns null!!!!!
        System.out.print(pictures.getName());

        line = null;
    }

    else {
        System.out.println("end of loop");

    }

}

}
```

Picture class

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.*;

public class Picture <E extends Shape>  {

 private  ArrayList<Shape> shapes;
 private String name;

public Picture() {

 shapes = new ArrayList<Shape>();


}


 public String getName() {
    //System.out.println("getting the name");
        return name;
    }

  public String setName(String name) {
 // System.out.println("setting the name " + name);
       this.name = name;
       return name;
  }



  public boolean addShape(E newA) {
     // System.out.println("add shape" + newA);
        boolean b = shapes.add(newA);
        return b;
    }



public void draw(String name) {
    DrawingPanel panel = new DrawingPanel(600, 600);
    Graphics g =  panel.getGraphics();

        for (Shape shape : shapes) {
      System.out.print("this is cool");
      shape.draw(g, 0, 0);



      }


}
 public String toString(String name) {

     String s = "Picture " + name + " hosts these shapes:\n";
     for (int i = 0; i < shapes.size(); i++) {
    s += "   "  + shapes.get(i).toString() + "\n";
     }
    return s;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `pictures = new Picture<Shape>();` doesn't affect the global value of `pictures`; it only affects the local value of `pictures` in `txtAnalysis()`. A simple code shift should get you the result you're looking for, by setting the value of `pictures` in a place where it will actually stick:

```
static void readLines(ArrayList<Picture> collection) throws Exception {
    Picture<Shape> pictures = null; //Just do null here
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Please enter the file name ---> ");
    fileName = input.next();

    FileReader fr = new FileReader(fileName);
    BufferedReader inFile = new BufferedReader(fr);

    // loop through lines
    while ((line = inFile.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
        if (line.startsWith("start picture")) {
            String picName = line.split(" ")[2];
            pictures = new Picture<Shape>();

            //set the name here
            pictures.setName(picName);    

            //here it works
            System.out.print(pictures.getName());
        }
        else {
            txtAnalysis(line, collection,pictures);
        }
    }

    // close file
    inFile.close();

}

public static void txtAnalysis(String name, ArrayList<Picture> collection, Picture<Shape> pictures ) {


    if (line.startsWith("circle")) {
        String[] parts = line.split(" ");
        int x = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
        int y = Integer.parseInt(parts[2]);
        int z = Integer.parseInt(parts[3]);


        //new object circle
        Circle c1 = new Circle("circ", x, y, z); 

        //add object
        System.out.println("calling add " + c1);
        pictures.addShape(c1);


    }
    else if (line.startsWith("rectangle")) {

        String[] parts = line.split(" ");
        int x = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
        int y = Integer.parseInt(parts[2]);
        int z = Integer.parseInt(parts[3]);

        //new object rectangle
        Rectangle r1 = new Rectangle("rect", x, y, z); // small and upper

        //add object

        pictures.addShape(r1);  
    }

    else if (line.startsWith("draw")) {
        collection.add(pictures);

        //problem here
        pictures.draw(pictures.getName());


        //returns null!!!!!
        System.out.print(pictures.getName());

        line = null;
    }

    else {
        System.out.println("end of loop");

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks I knew I was close. What would I have to do to call the Picture (collection of shapes) and draw them.` for(Picture item : collection) {
                  if (item.getName.equals(label)) {
                   System.out.println("calling add " + label);
                  pictures.draw(label);
                  
                
              }
              }`

Comment: You could put that `for` loop right below `readLines(collection);`. In terms of actually drawing them to the GUI, I haven't done that in a little while in Java, so start with Google then post a new question if necessary.